# selecting multiple check boxes or radio buttons from different accordions and then displaying them

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a custom cricket team and select multiple players from different teams and then displaying them

```js
function getMultipleCheckbox(inputdata) {
  var selectedItems = [];
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputdata.length; i++) {
    if (inputdata[i].checked) {
      selectedItems[count] = inputdata[i].value;
      count++;
    }
  }
  for (var loop = 0; loop < selectedItems.length; loop++) {
    console.log(selectedItems[loop]);
  }
  return selectedItems;
}
```

```html
<p>Select players</p>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="owns" value="player1">player1<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="owns" value="player2">player2<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="owns" value="player3">player3<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="owns" value="player4">player4<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="owns" value="player5">player5<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="owns" value="player6">player6<br/>
  <input type="button" value="Get Values" onclick="getMultipleCheckbox(this.form.owns);" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @fourth bird :- i want to make a custom cricket team by adding players from different teams and adding players should be done using checkboxes

Comment: The code in your question logs the selected players. I think you should show the code where you encounter a problem implementing your solution. You might take a look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).